# SQL: Check if multiple records exist in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database, I have a table with a many-to-many relationship to several other tables. I'd like to know, for several records at a time, whether an item exists in each of the other tables. Here's a simple example diagram:

```
--------------- 
| base_table  |
---------------
| key | name  |
---------------
| 1   | item1 |
| 2   | item2 |
| 3   | item3 |
| 4   | item4 |
---------------

-------------------------------
| table_2                     |
-------------------------------
| key | base_key  | other_key |
-------------------------------
| 1   | 1         | 1         |
| 2   | 1         | 2         |
| 3   | 1         | 3         |
| 4   | 2         | 1         |
| 5   | 2         | 4         |
| 6   | 4         | 4         |
-------------------------------

-------------------------------
| table_3                     |
-------------------------------
| key | base_key  | other_key |
-------------------------------
| 1   | 2         | 1         |
| 2   | 3         | 2         |
-------------------------------
```

And then I'm looking for output like this:

```
-----------------------------------
| name  | in_table_2 | in_table_3 |
-----------------------------------
| item1 | true       | false      |
| item2 | true       | true       |
| item3 | false      | true       |
| item4 | true       | false      |
-----------------------------------
```

I'm using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I liked @GordonLindoff's post, I thought the following would have worked just as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       b.Name,
       in_table_2 = CASE WHEN c.Base_key IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
       in_table_3 = CASE WHEN d.Base_key IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM Base_Table b
    LEFT JOIN Table_2 c
        ON b.key = c.Base_Key
    LEFT JOIN Table_3 d
        ON b.key = d.Base_Key;
```

I'd also reiterate his comment about 1's and 0's in SQL. If you *really, really* need  "True" or "False" in your display, do it on the front end, or change the 0 and 1 in the case statements to False and True, respectively.

Anyone have any objections to this?

I did to a SQLFiddle, listed here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d6547/28

Comment: Both this solution and @GordonLindoff's work for me. I do find this to be a little easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `union all` and aggregation to get which keys are in which tables:

```
select base_key, max(in_2) as in_2, max(in_3) as in_3
from ((select distinct base_key, 1 as in_2, 0 as in_3
       from table2
      ) union all
      (select distinct base_key, 0 as in_2, 1 as in_3
       from table3
      )
     ) t
group by base_key;
```

This returns "1" if the key is in the table and "0" if it is not.  SQL Server does not have boolean types and it seems silly to create a string for this purpose.

If you actually need the name instead of the key value, just join it in.

Comment: I'm just curious why you chose this route over the left joins?   I like this code.  Check my posted code for reference.

Comment: @TinyHaitian . . . It is usually much more efficient to do `select distinct` on a single table than on the results of `join`s.  I would expect this to have better performance on large tables.